# Oracle vs SQL Server query optimization main difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, query-optimization

I am doing a paper about query optimization in different DBMS, and I am trying to find core differences in those.

Both use CBO, cost based optimization in the same way, parse the query -> generate plans -> pick best one given statistics about the database.

I'm still researching information on those two engines, but if someone knows how they differ (or not) will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not a comprehensive answer at all, but wanted to give you my insight. In short, Oracle has a much more developed SQL optimizer.

For starters, Oracle has much more algorithms to choose from. This means, sometimes Oracle distinguish between subtle differences and offer, let's say, three algorithms; MySQL (under the same circumstances) only has one to choose from. Therefore, Oracle has better options for particular cases.

Another difference is that MySQL's execution plans are not very readable. I'm not saying they are bad internally, just that the `explain extended` doesn't tell you many specifics. Oracle makes a very clear difference between **access** and **filter** predicates, while in MySQL you don't really know what's going on.

Oracle has many algorithms suitable for parallel processing in multi servers, while MySQL is limited to multiple thread in the same machine. This can make a difference for highly parallelisable queries than benefit for multi-servers.

Oracle still has a RBO (Rule-Based Optimizer) than can be useful on some occasions. MySQL doesn't. Anyway, Oracle recommends not to use it, but it's still there if you need it.

Oracle offers a myriad of "hints" to the optimizer in the form of comments (`/* ... */` as far as I remember?) where you can tweak the execution plan to suit your needs. MySQL has fewer "clauses" for this.

Comment: I think I misread MySQL. My bad. I'll leave this answer here anyway, since it can give you ideas on what to ask about SQL Server.